# How to read HTML text inside body of mail using Javax.mail

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, multipart

I have written following code to read text  from body of a mail

```
private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException {
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
            result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
            break; // without break same text appears twice in my tests
        } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
            String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
            result = result + "\n" + Jsoup.parse(html).text();//html;// + org.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
        } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
            result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Problem I am facing to retrieve HTML content. It's only returning text content and omitting HTML tags.

Comment: "It's only returning text content and omitting HTML tags" -- that is what `Jsoup.parse(html).text()` does. If you want the tags, try using `html` directly.

Comment: But how to get the raw html content?

Answer (score 0):

the **break** is culprit for you. I saw the comment that result gets repeated and got the hint.

this will work for you -

```
public String getTextFromMimeMultipart(
MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
String result = "";
  int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
     if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
    /*
    result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
    break; 
    */ 
     // without break same text appears twice in my tests
} else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
    String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
    //html has all the html tags for you
    result = result + "\n" + html; //org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
} else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
    result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
    
  }
}
return result;
   }
```